# resharper code analysis using Command line tool (inspectcode.exe)

Tags: c#, resharper

In My C# language sln file contains two projects. first project has the actual code & second project has the unittest cases for the first project. but while am doing the resharper code analysis using Command line tool (inspectcode.exe).

for both project resharper doing the inspection in the unit test project only, not on the Actual code file.

'

```
package org.sonar.plugins.resharper;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.sonar.api.utils.command.Command;
import org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandException;
import org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandExecutor;

public class ReSharperExecutor
{
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReSharperExecutor.class);

  public void execute(String executable, String project, String solutionFile, File rulesetFile, File reportFile, int timeout)
  {
    Command cmd = Command.create(getExecutable(executable)).addArgument("/output=" + reportFile.getAbsolutePath()).addArgument("/no-swea").addArgument("/project=" + project).addArgument("/profile=" + rulesetFile.getAbsolutePath()).addArgument("/no-buildin-settings").addArgument(solutionFile);

    int exitCode = CommandExecutor.create().execute(cmd, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(timeout));
    if (exitCode != 0) {
      throw new CommandException(cmd, "ReSharper execution failed with exit code: " + exitCode, null);
    }
  }

  private static String getExecutable(String propertyValue)
  {
    String execName = "inspectcode.exe";
    if (!propertyValue.endsWith(execName)) {
      return new File(propertyValue, execName).getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return propertyValue;
  }
}'
```

Where I need to do the change to do the Resharper analysis for the Actual code.

Executing command: cd:/inspectcode.exe /output=cd:\resharper-report.xml /no-swea /project=* /profile=cd:.sonar\resharper-sonarqube.DotSettings /no-buildin-settings cd:\XXXX.sln

Comment: Normally, you'd just call inspectcode on the solution file. What are those `cd:` parameters?

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for your reply. Here cd means Corresponding Folder directory of those files (or file folder location).

Comment: Can you first eliminate all other possible mistakes, by calling `inspectcode.exe` directly in your solution folder?

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for your kind reply. I tried & called the inspectcode.exe & passed the solution directly as input for the inspectcode but it always searching for the unittest projects & gives analysis report for that unittet file & if the unittest files missing in that solution the throw an error as **No files to inspect were found.**   Executing command: cd:/inspectcode.exe /output=cd:\resharper-report.xml /no-swea /project=* "cd:/Project.sln"

Answer (score 0):

The above issue was caused bcoz the VS build version different in the

1.project built machine(**VS2015**) &

2.project analysis happening machine(**VS2013**),

so its not show any error details in log of the machine **2**.

After testing the analysis in the built machine i got the root cause of the issue(Few of the dependency library of the project was missed which should be availble under MSBuild folder{Msbuildfolder->Microsoft->visualstudio->version}) & fixed it(by replacing the missing dll's).
Now Analysis running successfully.